# Onmouseover change picture and font color using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm loss somewhere in my coding. I really new in jquery. I have a span, which in my span contains img and font. I want when user mouseover and mouseout the image and font change.

Here my HTML, i have to put `<?php echo $tododetail_id; ?>` in my span id because this is looping process

```
<span style='float:right;cursor:pointer;' id='delete<?php echo $tododetail_id; ?>'>
    <img id='imgdel' src='images/delete_icon_disabled.png'/>&nbsp;
    <font id='fontdel' style='text-decoration:underline;' color='#BDBDBD'>
    <?php echo lang['DETAIL_REMOVE_CMT_B']; ?></font>
</span>
```

Here my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("span[id^='delete']").hover(function() {
        $("#imgdel").attr('src', '/images/reply_icon.png');
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', '/images/reply_icon_disabled.png');      
    });
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: [Don't use the font tag anymore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

Comment: [jsless alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/vRe8q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one problem (besides using the font tag, this should really be done with css), the id should be unique. If you loop this code, you will have multiple img tags with id "imgdel". Afaik jQuery will not return a list for selector $('#imgdel') but only the first one matched. So i would try changing the php part to

```
<img class='imgdel' src='images/delete_icon_disabled.png'/>&nbsp;
```

and then doing

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("span[id^='delete']").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('img.imgdel').attr('src', '/images/reply_icon.png');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('img.imgdel').attr('src', '/images/reply_icon_disabled.png');      
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you have repeated spans like that on the page your html is invalid in that the img and font elements will not have unique ids, and then in your JS when you try to select an img with `$("#imgdel")` it will just find the first one (in most browsers), not the one that you hovered over.

You need instead to select the elements in a way that relates them to the particular span that was hovered. Within your hover handlers `this` will reference the span in question, so then you can use the [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find) to get to the img that that particular span contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("span[id^='delete']").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', '/images/reply_icon.png');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', '/images/reply_icon_disabled.png');      
    });
});
```

If you do that you can remove the id attributes from the img and font elements.

> *"I want when user mouseover and mouseout the image and font change."*

You don't actually say what you want to do to change the font, but you can use the same technique as above to select the font element, i.e., `$(this).find("font")`. (Why are you using font elements at all? That's *so* 1990s...)

Note also that your code would be neater if you assigned a common class to your span elements instead of the inline `style="..."` attribute (you can keep the id attribute if needed for something else), say something like this:

```
<span class="superSpan" id='delete<?php echo $tododetail_id; ?>'>
```

And then add this to your style sheet:

```
span.superSpan { float:right;cursor:pointer; }
```

...and change your JS to:

```
$("span.superSpan").hover(...
```

Comment: hahaha..thanks anyway..i know that it's really old style..since i really new in coding..so just try whatever i know.. :)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 $('#imgdel').attr('src', '/images/reply_icon_disabled.png');
```

instead of

```
 $(this).attr('src', '/images/reply_icon_disabled.png');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CZDWF/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("span[id^='delete']").hover(function() {
        $('#imgdel').attr('src', '/images/reply_icon.png');
    }, function() {
        $('#imgdel').attr('src', '/images/reply_icon_disabled.png');      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a hard coded image and font style. You can handle this with CSS. 
else in multiples with jQuery you need to try different method

Comment: _"You can handle this with CSS"_ - How? _"else in multiples with jQuery you need to try different method"_ - And that method would be...what? (As it stands, this answer is more of a comment, no?)